# Non-fluent preparation of queries in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a little bit of code in my model that looks like this:

```
query = open

if options.has_key? "user_id"
  query = query.where({
    :user_id => user_id
  })      
end

if options.has_key? "shop_id"
  query = query.where({
    :shop_id => shop_id
  })
end
```

Out of curiosity, is there a way I can tell my query object to simply "retain" the where clauses I'm assigning it (say if both :shop_id and :user_id exist).  Thus preventing me from always having to assign the result back to the local query variable?

Comment: why are you not using scopes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

for example you will have:

```
scope :for_user, lambda { |user| where(user_id: user.id) }
scope :for_shop, lambda { |shop| where(shop_id: shop.id) }
```

then to call both of them

```
model.for_user(@user).for_shop(@shop)
```

Comment: That didn't even occur to me!  I've been doing a bunch of refactoring and am reading the Rails Antipatterns book.  They show the lambda scope technique in there.  I guess I didn't make the connection! <more>

Comment: One concern however is that it'll move some of the conditional code back into my controller.  Is that the right thing to have happen in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to judge till I know what you are exactly trying to achieve in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a method in your model

**for user**

```
def for_user(user)
  where("user_id = ?", user.id)
end
```

**and for shop**

```
def for_shop(shop)
  where("shop_id = ?", shop.id)
end
```

you can also combine this two methods

```
def for_user_or_shop(user_shop)
  where("#{user_shop}_id = ?", user_shop.id)
end
```

**Note: If you pass scope then it's better then methods so use scopes**